# PHP structuring techniquies

Tags: php, optimization

I am writing a website in PHP where the aim is to allow the users to enter some monthly data, this is stored in MySQL, and at any point a user can view statistics to do with there data. I have all the basics done, however my code is completely unreadable, it is a mass of if statements, with no obvious structure, even with comments it's fairly opaque. How should I structure my code elegantly, and in what way should I utilise the OOP features of PHP.

Comment: This question is way to broad to be answerable. Get a book and read into what OOP means, try to understand the concept and then give it a try. Come back if you face any specific problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. I can only tell you what I generally do, not if it's the 'best' way or if there are more transparent workflows... just that it works for me very well ;)

First thing, and most important:
get rid of ALL non-php code in your php, for html display use templates either make a template system yourself or get one off the shelf (smarty for example).

Try to identify structures you use very often (like sql conenction and access) and put those into classfiles (you can easily change your sql system that way if you need to, by just editing ONE file, not countless others too)
Now find duplicate codeflow (mostly identical if-else-structures and so on)
and create functions for them to replace the original code with said function.
maybe even create more classes for functions that belong to a certain task.

So you end up with one class for the db, one for user information and editing, one for adding, editing and removing informations, and one for html output (and maybe even more)

Now set up your file system accordingly (put class files into a subfolder, templates in another, the same for images, javascripts etc.pp)

Next: Find all "settings"
All predefined values that may need to be changed, and put those into a settingsfile (init.php for example) maybe even as a class construct.

And as the last part, clean up all the mess inside single phps you cannot reduce further.
First: all the setup, include the files(classes) you need setup define the constants you will need for this script etc.
Second: all the script functions either in alphabetical or logical order.
and last the codeflow.

And that's it (a lot of work...) But you'll end up with a structure that I find easy to maintain. If you need to edit a setting, than it is in the init.php for sure, you want to change some db-structures or have changed your database, then you'll just need to update your sql.php and the like.

If someone else has to maintain the code too, you'll most likely will have to comment each file properly as well, personally I use comments for myself as well, since I have some scripts that needed to be changed after five or more years, that way I still know what goes where ;)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading up on code cohesion and loose coupling, those are important concepts which you need to familiarize yourself with if you're to build great, maintainable applications.

You should also catch-up on design patterns and common usage cases, if not all of them - atleast the big ones, which are IMO: singletons, factories, DI and IoC (you see those across the board).

Once you've got the theoratical thinking going, you should start writing your code in an indsutry-standard type of way, which for PHP is MVC - you can use one framework, whichever really doesn't matter much, once you've learnt one framework - reading alot of other projects code will be very easy because it usually follows the same pattern with some written better than others.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are in need of a framework to structure your code. Luckily for you, this problem has been solved by many. CodeIgniter, Cake, Zend, Kohana, Symfony, Yii, Slim, Laravel, Fuel, the list goes on.

I highly recommend you look into [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) as your first PHP framework. The documentation and community are both second-to-none.

Answer (score 0):

You may use some kind of PHP framework like Yii, Zend, Symfony or Kohana. MVC separation will be your good friend.